# Why is there a gap between the lines of text?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I can't figure out why there is a space between each line of text when I run this code:

```
file = open("Children.txt", 'a')
    file.write("\n" + childName)
    file.close()

    file = open("Children.txt", 'r')
    lineList = file.readlines()
    sorted(lineList)
    print("List of children's names in alphabetical order:")
    for line in lineList:
        print(line)
    file.close()
```

The spaces between each line only appear when I use the sorted() function. If I don't include it in the code and just use the print(file) function, the results display without a space between the lines of text. However I need the results to display alphabetically and that's why I use the sorted() function.

Comment: Try this: `print(line, end="")`

Comment: Print adds linefeed lineiterator keeps it: printed twice

Comment: BTW, it's a bit nicer if you put the End of Line character `\n` at the end of the line. That way, your file will always end in a `\n`; some tools won't handle text files properly if the file doesn't end in a EOL, eg the last line may not be displayed.

Comment: I'd be very surprised if `print(file)` printed the unsorted names, one per line. It _should_ print the repr of the file handle, eg `<_io.TextIOWrapper name='Children.txt' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>`. Are you _sure_ you're showing us your real code?

Comment: @PM2Ring Where is `print(file)` being called?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ The OP says "If I don't include it in the code and just use the print(file) function"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`f.readlines()` does not strip trailing newlines when reading in the file. Your list items will contain a trailing newline, which is printed out. Incidentally, `print` *also* adds a newlines at the end of input, meaning each line is printed with *two* newlines.

You can change this by either stripping newlines, or `print`ing with `end=""`:

```
for line in lineList: 
    print(line.rstrip())  # or print(line, end="")
```

Furthermore, `sorted` is not an inplace function. If you want to sort inplace, call `.sort()`.

```
lineList.sort()
```

Comment: What is the difference between print(line.rstrip())  and print(line, end="") in terms of advantages and disadvantages? Very helpful answer by the way, I used the .rstrip()  option and it works very well. I just want to make sure I'm using the best option. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @sleepylog It's a matter of preference mostly. I think `print(..., end="")` is slightly faster because `rstrip` is an overhead. But it is up to you.

Comment: Thank you, I'll got with the (line, end="") option for now and see how it goes.  You've been a great help. Cheers!